# Failed to load the "Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/totals" component

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I'm getting an error on the checkout page. Magento (2.3.1), PHP (7.1). If I'm activating the default theme (Luma) then working correctly. that error showing on my custom theme only. I need urgently help.

Error:--

> [2019-07-08 03:58:32] [ERROR] Failed to load the
>   "Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/totals" component.
>   console-output-handler.js:34:25 [2019-07-08 03:58:32] [ERROR] Failed
>   to load the "Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/tax" component.
>   console-output-handler.js:34:25 [2019-07-08 03:58:32] [ERROR] Failed
>   to load the "Vertex_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/tax-messages"
>   component. console-output-handler.js:34:25 [2019-07-08 03:58:32]
>   [ERROR] Failed to load the
>   "Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/subtotal" component.
>   console-output-handler.js:34:25 [2019-07-08 03:58:32] [ERROR] Failed
>   to load the "Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/grand-total"
>   component. console-output-handler.js:34:25 [2019-07-08 03:58:32]
>   [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Weee/js/view/cart/totals/weee"
>   component. console-output-handler.js:34:25 [2019-07-08 03:58:33]
>   [ERROR] Failed to load the
>   "Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/shipping-estimation" component.

Comment: Is your custom theme installed correctly?

Comment: Yes, I created my custom theme and when I'm changing the default.xml with new one then working correctly.

Comment: I have the same problem, could you help me and explain to me how you did it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

this error was caused in my case because the block **checkout.cart.shipping** had been removed from the **checkout_cart_index** handle.
I added it again and worked fine.

Comment: Thanks! It saves my day!